# DataTable duplica las filas al mostrar datos

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo implementado un data table para carga de facturas de compra, pero en algunos momentos me duplica las filas, verifico en la base de datos y solo esta ingresado una, pero en el datatable con vista al usuario me salen el doble.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es el codigo de javascript para el datatable

```
 var FacturasCompras = $("#Dt-facturas").DataTable({
 "bDestroy": true,
 "ajax":{
"method":"POST",
"url":"php/mod_retenciones.php",
"data":{"tipo":"7", "epkey":$('#keyeff').text()}
 },
 dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-3'B>>
    <'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
    <'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>`,
 buttons: [
 {
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  orientation: 'landscape',
  pageSize: 'A4',
  download: 'open',
   exportOptions: {
  columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7 ]
  },
  title: 'Factura de compras',
  className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
  text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Reporte PDF',
  titleAttr:'Exportar en pdf'
  },
  {
  extend: 'excel',
  text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Reporte Excel',
  className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
  exportOptions: {
  columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8 ]
  }
  }
  ],
   "columns":[ 
    {"data":null, render: function (data) {
    if(data.cabf_numero.length>15){
    return ( data.cabf_numero.substring(24,27) + ' - 
    '+data.cabf_numero.substring(27,30)+' - 
    '+data.cabf_numero.substring(30,39));
   }else{
     return ( data.cabf_numero.substring(0,3) + ' - 
     '+data.cabf_numero.substring(4,7)+' - '+data.cabf_numero.substring(8)); 
   }

   }},
   {"data":"cabf_fecha"},
   {"data":"prov_nombre"},
   {"data":"prov_ruc"},
   {"data":"cabf_observacion"},
   {"data":"cabf_scero"},
   {"data":null, render: function (data) {

   return (parseFloat(data.cabf_total));

   }},
   {"data":null, render: function (data) {
    var ivac=((parseFloat(data.cabf_total) - 
    parseFloat(data.cabf_d12))*0.12).toFixed(2);
    return ivac
  }},
   {"data":null, render: function (data) {
  return ( (parseFloat(data.cabf_total) + parseFloat (data.cabf_scero) - 
parseFloat(data.cabf_d0)-parseFloat(data.cabf_d12)) + 
((parseFloat(data.cabf_total) - parseFloat(data.cabf_d12)) *0.12)).toFixed(2)
 }},  
{"data":"cabf_mes"},
{"data": null, "defaultContent":
'<div style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">'+
 '<a id="verDetalle" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Ver Detalles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'+
 '<a id="verpdf" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Ver Detalles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'+
 '<a id="deletefac" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'+
 '</div>',
 "targets": -1}
 ],
 "language": espa
 });
```